# How to make others use my Python Script

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-7-x64, paramiko

I am just finished with my script in Python and i want my collegues to use it as well. It runs in python 2.7 Windows 7 64 bit professional env.  Now comes the question:

How can i make them use my script in an easy way?

- First choice is the hard way, making them install python on their machines and then install paramiko,Tkinter . I had a very hard time finding & installing these modules (especially for windows binary files) and do not want to suffer from the same issues again.
- I am a newbie in this environment and I think there would be practical solutions to this problem. So i wanted to ask you guys , any ideas appreciated.

Comment: _make_ is a strong word.

Comment: sudo make install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use cx_freeze i checked it.

cx_Freeze is a module used to create the python scripts into an executable(.exe) file. It is very easy method.

1. Download and install cx_Freeze windows binary for your python version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
2. Find the location of the your source code folder. for example- I created a test.py and stored it in c:\samp. c:\samp\test.py

   ```
   x="hai this is an exe file created from python scripts using cxfreeze. Press Enter to exit >> "
   y=input(x)
   ```
3. Create a folder to store the build file(.exe and other files). for eg- i created a folder c:\samp\build\
4. Open Command Prompt(start->run type "cmd" press enter) and type `console`

   C:\Documents and Settings\suh>c:\python32\scripts\cxfreeze c:\samp\test.py --target-dir=c:\samp\build

for more options type `C:\Documents and Settings\suh>c:\python32\scripts\cxfreeze -help`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/)(windows), [`py2app`](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)(Mac OS X) or [`cx_freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) to convert your application to an executable.

`cx_Freeze` is cross platform and should work on any platform that Python itself works on.

Comment: cx_freeze does the work thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert it to an executable. py2exe is a module that does this for you.

Follow the tutorial [here](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: py2exe does not work. actually it works on my computer but fails in my collegue's pc. I cannot see the error since it closes the window immediately. i will try cx_freeze , let you guys know about the result. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller is the python .exe maker that I've had the most success with --> http://www.pyinstaller.org/